# Win-10 I accidentally moved my video folder to save videos directly to my D:\

Tags: windows-10

I accidentally moved my video folder to save videos directly to my D:\ and when I try to make it save to a child of that folder it won't let me

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Reset the Videos folder path using Location tab

> 1. Open This PC, right-click on Videos folder and click Properties
> 2. In the **Location** tab, type `D:\Videos` and click **Move**
> 3. Choose `No` when you're prompted to move the files to the new (original) location.
> 4. Move your videos files (if any) manually from `D:\` to `D:\Videos`

**Option 2:** Edit the registry and fix the user shell folder path for videos.

> 1. Start `regedit.exe` and go to the following branch:
>
>    > HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User
>    >     Shell Folders
> 2. Double-click `My Video` and update the path accordingly -- e.g., `d:\videos`
> 3. Quit the Registry Editor, logoff and login back to your account.
> 4. Move your videos files (if any) manually from D:\ to `D:\Videos`

See also: [Do not move special folders to the root!](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/do-not-move-special-folders-to-the-root-drive/)